# Usando menu ativo como input "radio"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou usando um menu horizontal do boostrap, sua estrutura é basicamente assim:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  ...
  <li data-type="news" id="5" role="presentation"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li data-type"sports" id="4" role="presentation"><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

A ideia é ao clicar em cada menu chamar uma função jquery para trazer resultados com ajax e também ativar o menu, se esta estrutura fosse uma lista de inputs do tipo "radio" seria mais prático e rápido para pegar todos os atributos, é possível, ao selecionar o menu, marcar o input "radio" oculta referente à este menu?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que fazer esse link entre os radios buttons e o menu vai ocasionar em mais trabalho, vai ser preciso eventos para manter ambos sincronizados etc...

Sinceramente eu não vejo porque criar esse esquema com os radios buttons, o que tu poderia fazer é criar um evento de `click` genérico para todos os itens do menu, e a partir dai acessar os atributos e chamar os ajax.

Para acessar o atributo `data-type` por exemplo, seria assim:

```
$("ul.nav li").click(function(e){
    var dataType = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-type');
    //...
});
```

Comment: Entendo, nesse caso, qual a melhor forma de ativar o menu? seria algo como uma classe, como eu removeria ela do menu anterior?

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 Exatamente, adicionar uma classe cumpriria essa função, tu pode criar algo como: Ao clicar no item do menu, remover a classe `active`(por exemplo) de todos os itens e depois adicionar a classe somente no item que foi clicado. ex: `$("ul.nav li").removeClass( "active" );`, provavelmente estes métodos irão te ajudar: [`removeClass`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/),[`addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/),[`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)